# SpringCloud - ConfigServer - RabbitMQ - Client doesn't receive message from ConfigService

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I'm trying to make a ConfigServer Remote and Client with Gitlab repository.
The ConfigServer receives the notification of push through a Webhooks, but it doesn´t send the message to the client. I run a RabbitMQ with Docker, and I can see in the rabbit's console that the services are connected with it. So I don´t know what is the problem.

The configServer pom file looks like:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

ConfigServes's propertie file looks like:

```
server.port:8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri:https://gitlab.com/user/repo-properties.git

spring.cloud.config.server.git.username:user
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password:pass

spring.rabbitmq.host:172.17.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username:guest
spring.rabbitmq.password:guest

spring.cloud.bus.enabled:true

management.security.enabled:false
spring.cloud.config.server.monitor.gitlab.enabled:true

spring.profiles.active:desa
```

The pom of the client looks like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the application.yml of the client looks like:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 172.17.0.1
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

  application:
    name: user-server-config
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
  profiles:
    active: desa
```

I run rabbit with Docker with: sudo docker run --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq

I created a Webhooks in Gitlab. When a push a change, the ConfigServer receives the notification of /monitor, but the client doesn't receives the changes, does not receive anything. I don't know how to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't include which version.

Comment: Hi @spencergibb , I'm sorry, I'm using  SpringBoot 1.5.2 and Spring Cloud Brixton.RELEASE. Thanks.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5.x only became supported in the Camden train (Camden.SR6 is the latest). Otherwise go back to 1.4.x and try with the latest Brixton release, Brixton.SR7.

Comment: Hi @spencergibb I changed the versions to 1.4.5.RELEASE and Camden.SR6. And it works! Thank you very much!